Doran Geo Algebra for Physicists Exercise 2.9
In the question says

The Cayley-Klein parameters are a set of four real numbers $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ subject to the normalisation condition $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2=1$
These can be used to paramaterise an arbitrary rotation matrix as follows:
$$U=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha^2+\beta^2-\gamma^2-\delta^2&2\left(\beta\gamma+\alpha\delta\right)&2\left(\beta\delta-\alpha\gamma\right)\\2\left(\beta\gamma-\alpha\delta\right)&\alpha^2-\beta^2+\gamma^2-\delta^2&2\left(\gamma\delta+\alpha\beta\right)\\2\left(\beta\delta+\alpha\gamma\right)&2\left(\gamma\delta-\alpha\beta\right)&\alpha^2-\beta^2-\gamma^2+\delta^2\end{pmatrix}$$
Can you relate the Cayley-Klein parameters to the rotor description?

I recognize the matrix to be something generated by unit quaternion, implying $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$ should be components of yz, xz, xy plane unit bivectors by looking at the diagonal elements. But I can't quite make the connection between quaternion (bivector) and this matrix. Moreover, the sandwiching of rotors are gone using matrix which further confuses me. What am I missing here?

You might find some insight reviewing the wiki article on three dimensional rotations:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions
The section discussing quaternions makes the connection to Euler angles.
Additionally, it is pointed out the related quaternion defined by
$\hat{\mathbf{q}}=q_{i}\mathbf{i}+q_{j}\mathbf{j}+q_{k}\mathbf{k}+q_{r}$
has the property
$q_{i}^{2}+q_{j}^{2}+q_{k}^{2}+q_{r}^{2}=1.$

I see every element is the component of the corresponding bivector! Thank you
